# Python selenium id number is dynamic

Tags: selenium, python-3.8

I have an html which looks as following:

```
<div class="v-window-outerheader"><div class="v-window-maximizebox" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="maximize button" id="38_window_maximizerestore"></div>
    <div class="v-window-closebox" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="close button" id="38_window_close"></div>
```

This code is for a message box which pops up on logging into the website.

I have been using the following code to click on the `X` on top right to close the message pop:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
path_to_chromedriver = r'C:\chromedriver'  # change path as needed
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
browser.get("https://ftrcenter.pjm.com/ftrcenter/pages/secure/")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="37_window_close"]'))).click()
```

But, the ID number `37_window_close` changes every so often. Today the id is `38_window_close`
Rest of the html code remains same. How do I modify my code so that my code doesn't break due to this change in ID?

The pop up box appears as following, where `X` is on top right to close it:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aria-label="close button"` attribute.

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@aria-label="close button"]'))).click()
```

Or class attribute.

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="v-window-closebox"]'))).click()
```

Or use contains with id

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id,"_window_close")]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic IDs, You can match the substring instead of the exact string.
Use Below XPath:

```
//div[contains(@id,"_window_close")]
```

OR CSS:

```
div[id*="_window_close"]
```

Hope this helps :)